# How to update a website's homepage to use a static AWS S3 site just for the homepage

Tags: seo, website-design, static-content, site-structure

I have developed the browser based game over at http://ninjawars.net.  Currently, the game site homepage is essentially like a single-page app, it is a php backed homepage with an iframe, links to various pieces of the game, and you login from the homepage to play.
I want to put a splash page in front of the site that is a static amazon S3 site http://ninjawars-splash.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ . 
 I was planning on 301 redirecting the homepage to a splash.ninjawars.net subdomain, and then linking from the splash page back to the main site, however I am concerned about breaking up the existing site structure and making things harder to be found in google.

What are my options for showing the static site in the place of the root homepage (and only for that / root url)?

Comment: Here is the documentation for assigning a domain name to an S3 bucket. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html  Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Not to my understanding, no, as I'm trying to put an S3 in the place of a single page, (or find out about some other approach), not set up a complete s3 site, which I already have above.

Comment: To serve a single page from a different server it usually means you have to reverse proxy it.